# Does Gradle Performance Scale Well With Number Of CPU Cores

Tags: android, performance, gradle, cpu

Curious if gradle build performance scales proportionally to CPU cores.

Considering single higher clocked vs dual Xeon workstation upgrade for gradle wrapper builds via Android Studio

Wondering if it's worth it considering I'm not bottlenecked by disk IO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there are two ways Gradle can utilize multiple CPU cores:

- Parallel build exection
- Parallel test execution

Parallel build execution only works on multi-project builds with decoupled projects and can be activated with `--parallel` on the command line. See 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:parallel_execution for more information.

Parallel test execution can be activated by setting `maxParallelForks` in a test task. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

You should also be aware of Configuration on demand for large multi-project builds: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand

So I'd say yes, Gradle performance scales well with multiple CPU cores.

Comment: What if its a single large project w/o any test execution?

Comment: --parallel did magic for me even if it wasnt multi-project. using gradle 6.7

Comment: In android development, is multi-project the same as multi-module?